# Instagram private API 403 even with cookies and headers

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram-api

Need your advise on avoiding 403 on private Isntagram APi usage.

Ive reused one of the isntagram **scraper** codes on web.
Ive done couple tries and even with headers and cookies all looks next.
There is not issue with getting info stragiht from post url and extracting it.
Though, post comment span across several pages and to switch to a next one i need to become authenticated.
This is just a first step to test authentication.

```
    from botocore.vendored import requests
    import urllib.parse
    import hashlib
    import json
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        CHROME_UA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
        def getSession(rhx_gis, csrf_token, variables):
            """ Get session preconfigured with required headers & cookies. """
            #"rhx_gis:csfr_token:user_agent:variables"
            print(variables)
            values = "%s:%s:%s:%s" % (
                    rhx_gis,
                    csrf_token,
                    CHROME_UA,
                    variables)
            x_instagram_gis = hashlib.md5(values.encode()).hexdigest()
        
            session = requests.Session()
            session.headers = {
                    'user-agent': CHROME_UA,
                    'x-instagram-gis': x_instagram_gis
                    }
            print(x_instagram_gis)
            session.cookies.set('ig_pr', '2')
            session.cookies.set('csrftoken', csrf_token)
        
            return session
        
        def runX():
            session = requests.Session()
            session.headers = { 'user-agent': CHROME_UA }
            response = session.get("https://www.instagram.com/selenagomez")
            data = json.loads(response.text.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0])
            csrf = data['config']['csrf_token']
            rhx_gis = data['rhx_gis']
            variables = '{"id":"460563723","first":10,"after":"AQBf8puhlt8nU2JzmYdMMTuH0FbMgUM1fnIOZIH7n94DM4VLWkVILUAKVB-5dqvxQEI-Wd0ttlEDzimaaqwC98jccQaDQT4tSF56c_NlWi_shg"}'
            session = getSession(rhx_gis, csrf, variables)
        
            query_hash = '33ba35852cb50da46f5b5e889df7d159'
            encoded_vars = urllib.parse.quote(variables, safe='"')
            url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=%s&variables=%s' % (query_hash, encoded_vars)
            print(url)
            opp = session.get(url)
            print(opp.status_code)
        runX();
```

UPDATE 16th of April - > Fixed

1. Issue fixed and 200 received now. Changing hash to query_hash = 'ac38b90f0f3981c42092016a37c59bf7'
   and removing user agent from x-instagram-gis calculation :

   values = "%s:%s:%s" % (
   rhx_gis,
   csrf_token,
   variables)

Answer (score 1):

As of 23 April 2018, it appears that you no longer need cookie management or the csrf token. The following should be all you need:

```
def getSession(rhx_gis, variables):
        values = "%s:%s" % (
                rhx_gis,
                variables)
        x_instagram_gis = hashlib.md5(values.encode()).hexdigest()

        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers = {
                'x-instagram-gis': x_instagram_gis
                }

        return session
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram change there API. It requires auth now. there is no way to use instagram graphql without auth.

You can also check here if the api need auth. if no return it means, need auth.

```
$ curl https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44&variables={"id":"460563723","first":10,"after":"AQBf8puhlt8nU2JzmYdMMTuH0FbMgUM1fnIOZIH7n94DM4VLWkVILUAKVB-5dqvxQEI-Wd0ttlEDzimaaqwC98jccQaDQT4tSF56c_NlWi_shg"}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove CHROME_UA from x-instagram-gis.

Comment: Removing User agent from x-instagram-gis causes 400

Comment: I was using a wrong hash for locactions . 
Looks like there are different has values depending on the hashtag , comment or etc used. 
Now i am getting 200

Comment: @DiV it's not working for me. What are are using as the string to hash for the x-instagram-gis header?